# Understanding this theorem about a continuous path from $a$ to $b$ that lies in $N_\epsilon(a) \cap M$ as well as in $N_\epsilon(b) \cap M$

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

I have a theorem here which says

If $M \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, connected and locally connected and $a,b \in M$ then there is for all $\epsilon>0$ a $\delta>0$ where $\delta \leq \epsilon$ such that whenever $$||a-b|| < \delta$$ there is a continuous path from a to b that lies in  $N_\epsilon(a) \cap  M$ as well as in $N_\epsilon(b) \cap  M$.

In terms of the notation: $N_{\delta} (a)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n| ||x-a| < \delta\}$ is the $\delta$ neighbourhood of $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$

What is this theorem trying to say?

What does $N_\epsilon(a) \cap  M$ mean?

Comment: This is pretty much the definition of locally connected (without which the conclusion would be false). For example, the union of $\{1/n\}\times [0,1]$ ($n\geq 1$), $\{0\}\times [0,1]$ and $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ is a comb which becomes rather dense towards the ordinal axis. It is connected but not locally connected. Given the point $(0,y)$ with $0<y\leq 1$ then any neighborhood of radius smaller than $y$ contains points arbitrarily close to $(0,y)$ but which can not be connected within the neighborhood. You should probably make a drawing to see this.

Comment: BTW: The def of locally connectivity:  Given $a\in M$ and $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ so that every $b\in M\cap N_\delta(a)$ may be connected to $a$ within the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $a$ (so you may go a bit out of the $\delta$ nghd to make the connection but not too much).